# Importing SVG sequence, joining all separate curves

Tags: python, bezier-curves, svg

I am trying to write a quick Python script that loads `.SVG` sequences placed in one folder, and cleanly joins all the curves that come with it. I managed to load the `.SVG`s fine, but I am currently still working on joining the curves.

Here's the code I have:

```
##################
import bpy
import glob
import os  

# path to your folder

importDir = "C:/tmp/silhouette_svg" 
print("Importing all SVG from this directory", importDir)

os.chdir(importDir)

for files in glob.glob("*.svg"):
    print( files, "... imported!" )
    bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath=files)
```

Blender's `Import Curve` should come with the *joined* option, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack script (not elegant at all) is something like below.

I manage to do these steps:
1) import svg
2) select and join them as one
3) rename it somewhat (not perfect)
4) turn each one into mesh (for remove doubles?)

```
############# IMPORTING ALL SVG WITH SEGMENTED
import bpy
import glob
import os  

# path to your folder

importDir = "C:/tmp/silhouette_svg" 
print("Importing all SVG from this directory", importDir)

os.chdir(importDir)

for files in glob.glob("*.svg"):
  print( files, "... imported!" )
  bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath=files)

  # deselect nothing, select all curves, join
  bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
  bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='CURVE')
  bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["Curve"]
  for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.select:obj.name = "snail.000"
  bpy.ops.object.join()
  bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
  bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

Any suggestions to make the code more elegant?

Comment: instead of changing directory:  https://gist.github.com/zeffii/16a7106fd55650cfe5436de1bbd851c7